# Create an interface for an Array with properties

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create an interface that reflects the type generated by:

```
const foo = Object.assign([1,2,3], {offset: 4});
```

I was considering:

```
interface Bar {
    [key: number]: number;
    offset: number;
}
```

But I still get errors when accessing Array prototypes (map/reduce/etc).

Comment: `number[] & { offset: number }`? You can't access array methods because you've only provided an index signature, not an array's methods. You need an intersection with an array type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you can have your interface `Bar` to be extending `Array` class:

```
const foo = Object.assign([1,2,3], {offset: 4});

interface Bar extends Array<Number> {
    offset: number;
}

function test(a: Bar) {
    console.log(a[0]);
    console.log(a.length);
    console.log(a.concat);
}

test(foo);
```

You can read more about [Interfaces Extending Classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#interfaces-extending-classes)

**UPDATE:**
In fact, you can create a separate type using intersections instead of creating a separate interface:

```
const foo = Object.assign([1,2,3], {offset: 4});

type Bar = number[] & {offset: number};

function test(a: Bar) {
    console.log(a[0]);
    console.log(a.length);
    console.log(a.concat);
}

test(foo);
```

Comment: That interface seems overkill, why not just use an intersection `type Bar = number[] & { offset : number }` ?

Comment: if I'm extending `Array<Number>` is the `[key: number]: number` still necessary?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks, you're right. Moreover, the composition might be more preferable. But this is just an answer to the question provided.

Comment: @Bradd you might be ok just with `interface Bar extends Array<Number> {
    offset: number;
}` then

Comment: @falinsky I think OP was using the interface as this is common in many langauges and is probably unaware of intersections, suggesting a different more in tune with the language solution seems reasonable to me

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir agree. Could you please provide your answer and I will remove my one?

Comment: @TobiasTengler run: `console.log(Object.assign([1,2,3], {offset: 4}))` and see the output.  It does in fact work.  Arrays are Objects like everything else in JavaScript.

Comment: @falinsky, you should supplement your answer to give the most complete rational for future visitors.

Comment: @falinsky Nah, You answer is fine, this is mostly nit picking, I don't see a reason to provide another similar answer. This would be it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDyAjAVgU2FAOgEMIIBLAczAAoBtARgBoAmRgZgF1GYBvEOOBBxQAXDAAsAXwCUAbgBQ8qAE8ADjhgAhIgCcUMMAFcAthhw7aHGADJe8mA5j9BwsUdPmFkxXENh8ZOAwUDjQ1ERi2jrSdo4woJAgADY4BEkgFOG0AAwccvaOCRDJqemZRGk4YBRQABb5cUUlaRnhBAnARFD53kqhUNQIIHJAA

Comment: check your browser console @TobiasTengler, your result has to do with their parser.